# Swift Core Data - storing an array of custom types

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, struct

I am trying to create a data model which mirrors a view model that I use to handle an API call, the idea being that I will be able to store all the necessary data in core data and then access it when the user is offline, effectively giving the app offline functionality.

However, there is one entity which I need to store which is an array of a custom class that I have in the app:

```
[OrderSheet]
```

This is a struct defined as follows:

```
struct OrderSheet {
    let order: SheetClass // codable class
    let sheet: Sheet // codable struct

    init(fuelOrder: SheetClass, sheet: Sheet) {
    self.order = order
    self.sheet = sheet
    }
}
```

How can I create an entity that would be capable of storing the above?

Comment: Create 3 entities for OrderSheet, Sheet and SheetClass

Comment: Or create only two entities, Sheet and SheetClass, with a many-many relationship between them (which is what OrderSheet seems to represent).

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to have an entity that holds only one `Data` field (Binary Data in xcdatamodel settings), which would be the orderSheet itself.

Before going with this solution, I'd like to mention that, one down side of this approach is; if later in the future, any of the models inside `OrderSheet` changes, you won't be able to retrieve already stored objects as conversion will fail. One way of overcoming this issue would be declaring everything inside `OrderSheet` and sub models as Optional. But if it is not so crucial, meaning, if not being able to read old models on user's device after an app update is okay, (maybe they will be replaced with new networking call) then you can go with not marking properties as optional either.

Lets imagine you create an entity named `OrderSheetManaged` with one field as I mentioned like following:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Entity)
public class OrderSheetManaged: NSManagedObject {

}

extension OrderSheetManaged {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<OrderSheetManaged> {
        return NSFetchRequest<OrderSheetManaged>(entityName: "OrderSheetManaged")
    }
    @NSManaged public var orderSheet: Data?
}
```

*I will write some code for NSManagedObjectContext, which is not directly related to your question, you should make research on how to initialise a core data stack and a managed context from it if you are not familiar with that since it is crucial.*

*I also do some force unwrapping for simplicity, make sure to not force unwrap where not needed in production code.*

Now whenever you have an actual `OrderSheet` object (it is orderSheet in my example below), that was parsed before, you are going to convert it to `Data` and persist it with new Core Data model as following:

```
// unrelated to question, it should already be initialised from core data stack, I just init with
// concurrency type to make compiler happy, dont do this before further research.
let yourManagedContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "OrderSheetManaged",
                                                   in: yourManagedContext)

let dataForCoreData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(orderSheet)

let managedOrderSheet = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: yourManagedContext)
managedOrderSheet.setValue(dataForCoreData, forKey: "orderSheet")
```

Now we have persisted your object as Data inside a wrapper core data model (`OrderSheetManaged`)

Let's see now how we can fetch these models from our core data and convert it back to OrderSheet model:

```
// when you fetch it
var orderSheets = [OrderSheet]()
let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "OrderSheetManaged")
var coreDataObjects: [NSManagedObject]!
do {
    coreDataObjects = try yourManagedContext.fetch(request) as? [NSManagedObject]

    for coreDataObject in coreDataObjects {
        if let orderSheetData = coreDataObject.value(forKey: "orderSheet") as? Data {
            let orderSheet = try! JSONDecoder().decode(OrderSheet.self, from: orderSheetData)
            orderSheets.append(orderSheet)
        }
    }
} catch {
    error
}
```

Now you will have all your stored order sheets inside `orderSheets` array.

You can also write some utility methods to easily modify core data models by converting `orderSheet` data inside of them to `OrderSheet` first and then again converting it back to `Data` after modifying and then persisting again with `setValue`.